# A coin is flipped 8 times. Assume that the coin is fair

Tags: probability

A coin is flipped 8 times. Assume that the coin is fair (that is, all outcomes are equally likely). What is the probability that the number of heads is different from the number of tails?

$n|S|=2^8$

Help me with this problem... please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome of the experiment is described by a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),
with $n=8$ ($n$ is the number of trials), $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (the probability of getting an head), and $X$ is the number of heads.

Of course, you have the same number of heads and tails when $X=4$. This event occurs probability:

$$P(X = 4) = {8 \choose 4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{8-4} = \frac{70}{256}$$

Therefore, the probability that the number of tails and heads is different is just:

$$1 - P(X=4) = \frac{186}{256} \simeq 0.73.$$

Answer (score 2):

We can recognize a random variable $X$ follows the binomial law $\mathcal B(8,\frac12)$ and you look for

$$\Bbb P(X\ne4)=1-\Bbb P(X=4)=1-{8\choose4}\left(\frac12\right)^{4}\left(\frac12\right)^{8-4}=1-{8\choose4}\left(\frac12\right)^{8}$$